# Clustered histograms in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a clustered histogram.  This is easy to do in Excel wit pivot tables, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do the equivalent in Tableau.

My data set is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVoLE.png)

I'd like to create a chart like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0KPt.png)

So, essentially two histograms overlapping, showing the relative frequency for each state separately, but in the same graph.  How do I do this in Tableau?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do it using dual axis

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dual axis function to achieve this

You need 2 measures in the pill, for example: Sales or Profit

Right click on Sales or Profit and select Dual Axis

[image]

If both are same data type, you can synchronize the axis so that you can do a comparison